# Application written in perl script and c language , which executes quick and why?

Tags: c, linux, perl

I am converting code written in `perl` to `C` language but before proceeding I would like to know the performance difference between `perl` execution and `c` language execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends entirely on what you are doing. Raw performance of an interpreted language like Perl isn't as good as C, but if you are accessing files, pulling information out of a database, or other things which aren't purely part of the language itself you'll find the performance difference is negligible and the benefit of an interpreted language is much easier maintainability.